# The method getService() is undefined for the type StorageOptions

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-storage, storage

I'm just trying out the FirebaseAdmin SDK and when I use the following code in Eclipse Java,

```
    Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
```

I get an error that says: "The type com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files The method getService() is undefined for the type StorageOptions."
I'm not sure if I am missing out on some dependencies here but these are what I have used so far:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
    <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
    <version>6.12.0</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
    <version>0.19.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
    <version>1.103.0</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.92.2</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-core-http</artifactId>
    <version>1.92.2</version>
</dependency>



<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.12</version>
</dependency>
```

No clue whats wrong....:/ Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Well, it turns out that I needed to add "requires google.cloud.core;" under the module file to get rid of the error.